# How to correctly get input data and call it in the function?

Tags: javascript, html

How to correctly get input data and call it in the function?
I try to call this function in submit button, but I can't see any action.

```
        <input style="display:none;" class="form-control col-md-5 col-8" id="pesel" minlenght="11"
                           maxlength="11"
                           type="text" name="pesel"
                           placeholder="PESEL" required>

        <p><input class="submit-button" type='submit' name='submit' value='Wyślij' onclick="isValidPesel()"></p>
        <span id="error"></span>
                 <script>
                 function isValidPesel(pesel) {
                    function validatepesel(pesel) {
                        var reg = /^[0-9]{11}$/;
                        if (reg.test(pesel) == false) {

                            console.log("error");
                            document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'Niepoprawny numer pesel';
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            var digits = ("" + pesel).split("");
                            if ((parseInt(pesel.substring(4, 6)) > 31) || (parseInt(pesel.substring(2, 4)) > 12))
                                return false;
                            console.log("Error");
                            document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'Niepoprawny numer pesel';
                            var checksum = (1 * parseInt(digits[0]) + 3 * parseInt(digits[1]) + 7 * parseInt(digits[2]) + 9 * parseInt(digits[3]) + 1 * parseInt(digits[4]) + 3 * parseInt(digits[5]) + 7 * parseInt(digits[6]) + 9 * parseInt(digits[7]) + 1 * parseInt(digits[8]) + 3 * parseInt(digits[9])) % 10;
                            if (checksum == 0) checksum = 10;
                            checksum = 10 - checksum;

                            return (parseInt(digits[10]) == checksum);
                        }
                    }
                    var pesel = document.getElementById("pesel").value;
                    console.log(pesel);
                }
                </script>
```

Comment: Dałeś ten kod w <script> :D?
Do you have your code in <script> tag?

Comment: @ncti, when you have writen your script tag, try ussing this `document.querySelector("[name='submit']").value;` instead of `document.getElementById("pesel").value;`

Comment: @dommilosz yes.

Comment: try `onclick="isValidPesel(document.getElementById('pesel').value)"`

Comment: @dommilosz not working.

Comment: What *is* the input you want to test? Is there another `<input type="text" id="pesel">` somewhere in the document?

Comment: <input style="display:none;" class="form-control col-md-5 col-8" id="pesel" minlenght="11"
                               maxlength="11"
                               type="text" name="pesel"
                               placeholder="PESEL" required>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick: (No change in the HTML)

```
<input style="display:none;" class="form-control col-md-5 col-8" id="pesel" minlenght="11" maxlength="11" type="text" name="pesel" value="324983274823" placeholder="PESEL" required>
<p>
    <input class="submit-button" type='submit' name='submit' value='Wyślij' onclick="isValidPesel()">
</p>
<span id="error"></span>
```

JavaScript: Error was you not calling the validatepesel function at the end.

```
function isValidPesel(pesel) {
    function validatepesel(pesel) {
        var reg = /^[0-9]{11}$/;
        if (reg.test(pesel) == false) {

            console.log("error");
            document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'Niepoprawny numer pesel';
            return false;
        } else {
            var digits = ("" + pesel).split("");
            if ((parseInt(pesel.substring(4, 6)) > 31) || (parseInt(pesel.substring(2, 4)) > 12))
                return false;
            console.log("Error");
            document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'Niepoprawny numer pesel';
            var checksum = (1 * parseInt(digits[0]) + 3 * parseInt(digits[1]) + 7 * parseInt(digits[2]) + 9 * parseInt(digits[3]) + 1 * parseInt(digits[4]) + 3 * parseInt(digits[5]) + 7 * parseInt(digits[6]) + 9 * parseInt(digits[7]) + 1 * parseInt(digits[8]) + 3 * parseInt(digits[9])) % 10;
            if (checksum == 0) checksum = 10;
            checksum = 10 - checksum;

            return (parseInt(digits[10]) == checksum);
        }
    }
    var pesel = document.getElementById("pesel").value;
    validatepesel(pesel);
}
```

Comment: I need to get value from input pesel
                         <input style="display:none;" class="form-control col-md-5 col-8" id="pesel" minlenght="11"
                               maxlength="11"
                               type="text" name="pesel"
                               placeholder="PESEL" required> and check it during submit

Comment: @ncti Please check. Updated the answer. Adding a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xof3mn1c/

Answer (score 0):

```
Method 1:
<input class="submit-button" type='submit' name='submit' value='Wyślij' onclick="isValidPesel(this)">
<script>
function isValidPesel(element) {
  console.log(element.value);
}

</script>
Method 2:
 <input type="hidden" value="Wyślij" id="myInput">
<input class="submit-button" type='submit' name='submit' onclick="isValidPesel(this)">
<script>
function isValidPesel() {
  var str = $("#myInput").val();
  console.log(str);
}
</script>
```

Comment: I hope it solves your problem. Mark the Answer Right if helpfull.